# How can I install WiFi dongle drivers on Linux without Internet access?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, pop-os

My PC has Windows and no Ethernet connection. I connect to the Internet via a USB WiFi dongle. In Windows the dongle drivers were automatically installed when I connected it to my PC.

I recently installed Pop!_OS on my PC (dual boot). The drivers did not automatically install for Linux. How can I install the drivers for my particular peripheral?

I would prefer if there was some way I can install the drivers without the use of the Internet, just as Windows did. If that is not possible I am open to any other way.

Here is a picture of the dongle. It is a TP-Link TL-WN722N:

[image: WiFi dongle in question]

Comment: you are assuming there *are* Linux drivers for your wifi dongle.  What make/model is it?

Comment: @Keltari 
the model is `TL-WN722N`, I've also added the image of the dongle in original post

Comment: Make/model is often not that relevant (different hardware revisions may have different chipsets), the chipset is what matters. Now that you're beginning your Linux journey you should get into the habit of using the proper tools, `lsusb` in this case to list all USB connected peripherals. The line about your WiFi dongle will show the chipset and that is what you should google about or ask questions with. According to https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:2357-010c it's a "Realtek RTL8188EUS" (but you should confirm anyway).

Comment: What kernel are you running in Pop!_OS? $ uname -a # will tell you. Built in drivers are listed at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org . The v2 looks like it is rtl8188eu which might only be in bleeding edge testing kernels. You would have to download from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/blob/master/README.md and compile. You'll probably need more help and the development packages and header files packages will need to be installed on your system.

Comment: @AlexCannon The driver you suggested *probably* won't work with the current kernels. There are better as already discussed in comments of the answer below (and the answer has been updated accordingly).

Comment: Likely the easiest thing to do is just buy a wifi dongle that IS supported by linux.

Comment: @Keltari Absolutely. Nitpicking: A WiFi dongle that is natively supported by the Linux kernel. This is because almost everything out there is supported by Linux but a few like this one require additional drivers installed by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Linux drivers for TL-WN722N-V2 are not found on the TP-LINK
website.

Some open-source drivers can be found in Github, but they are not
very recent. Another problem is that they are distributed in
source format and require compilation, which assumes a working
Linux computer with an internet connection (unfortunately).

- [abhijeet2096/TL-WN722N-V2](https://github.com/abhijeet2096/TL-WN722N-V2).
- [TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink](https://github.com/mfruba/kernel/tree/master/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink)
- **Note** : A more recent driver was found by user
  ChanganAuto at
  [aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus).

I just wanted to say that you can avoid this problem entirely
by putting the Pop!_OS distribution inside Windows, so using
in effect the Windows driver (which works).

You may do that by either creating a Pop!_OS virtual machine on
Windows, or by installing a WSL distribution.
For the latter, see for example
[aidenfoxx/wsl2-popos - PopOS 20.04 WSL2 Instance](https://github.com/aidenfoxx/wsl2-popos).

Comment: Indeed they aren't very recent and likely not to work with newer kernels. This one https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus *probably* works. This chipset have been quite problematic in Linux.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Thanks - I added this information to my answer.